# How to distinguish flavors vs in app purchases

Tags: kotlin, android-productflavors

Ok this is more informative question than on a coding question. However this is a two part question.

When building the flavors for example an MP3 player.. you would have free and premium. I started designing a flavor app of an MP3 player to start learning Flavors and Build variants.

What i am trying to understand is when building the flavor is all of the design for the flavors built in `Project` then each flavor is specific. Premium features for Premium and free features for free. I understand that.

However what i am not understanding about the design is when i design my login with firebase how do i call the flavor thats appropriate. For testing purposes lets forget firebase. Here is an example:

MainActivity has two buttons. One will point to the free and the other paid. So if i press the free button do provide an intent that points to the flavor as this:

`val i = Intent(......buildConfig.flavors.free)`

Or would i place the package name in where the buildConfig would go. This is not actual code this is just an example.

Keep in mind i have never built a flavored app. So this is a learning point for me.

My original idea was have a free version as default with an in app purchase. You use the in app purchase and if the purchase is successful then the premium would take effect.. the only differences in the actual deaign would be those premium features are enabled.

So the first question would be: Is there really a difference between same design flavors versus in app purchases?

The second question is: when building a flavor app with the same design. Do you have to use flavors, example Free/paid, if the design never changes.

Like i said this is a learning process and all my apps on google play is just a flavorless app with adMob banner ad. So i an wanting to venture out to a more simple aspect than having two apps on google play one app for the free and another app for premium.

I think it would be easier to do flavors. However i have never done a flavored app and all the research i have done does not give clear instructions. They all stop after the gradel file implementation.

So any direction would help with is flavors a must or is it more headache to deal with in my case for learning purposes versus real world application.

Comment: *"Is there really a difference between same design flavors versus in-app purchases?"* What do you mean by "same design flavors"? Personally, I would not create a premium flavor of an app and risk potentially running afoul of their "repetitive content" policy, even if that is a long shot. Among the apps from big publishers, I've only noticed premium flavors for apps that predate the introduction of IAP support in Google Play. As a small indie dev, I don't have the power to fight Google's bot if it incorrectly declares one of my premium apps a violation of "repetitive content".

Comment: So when it comes to flavors it would best to stay away from flavors as an Indie Dev.. I see these apps where you have the same app free with ads and you look for their other app premium. You buy the premium before install. So in theory it's best to keep free vs paid versions complete separate apps... The concept same design one with ads and you buy the premium to do away with ads. That was the concept building flavors vs in app  purchases vs 2 complete different apps

Comment: I used flavors back before the store supported IAP. Now I continue using flavors for legacy support of those premium apps, although I have unpublished them from the store. I still update the premium versions for the benefit of people who bought them before I unpublished them. Regardless, I *still* use flavors in my new apps because I have Google Play and Amazon App Store variants. I might be overly cautious by avoiding having premium versions of my apps, but it's also easier (for me and for customers) to manage only one version of the app being on the store.

Comment: So for a free app with the option to purchase premium. Would you recommend flavors or in app purchase. I am only releasing to Android. So in theory you sign in which would be connected to Firebase. So from the login how do you specify which application file goes to the user. As example in question. I can build the entire app. I just don't know the mechanics of flavors and I can't find any tutorials beyond gradle

Comment: I think I already said I recommend in-app purchases because a single app's easier to manage and you don't risk Google Play's policy bot banning you for life for violating the repetitive content policy. If you're doing this with flavors, you can create BuildConfig fields or String resources that have different values based on which flavor it is. Even something as simple as `BuildConfig.IS_PREMIUM` as a Boolean that you use in your code to determine the content. With an in-app purchase, you would check the purchase state, which you can get through the API or store in SharedPreferences.